# Package all the SQL create table statements into a single statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I finished writing multiple SQL statements in order to generate my final table `CCtbase2`. What I want to do next is to package the entire SQL code into a single SQL statement avoiding creating multiple temporary tables. I just want to write my query in a way in which I will be creating my final table without creating multiple temporary tables but I am not sure how to go about it and I apologise for not providing sample of the tables.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_t1;

Select PID, CID ,CCID, CExpiry, PStatusID, PDate into temp_t1 
FROM  TABLE1 where PStatusID = 1001;

-- Applying filters

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_t2;
SELECT * into temp_t2 
FROM TABLE2 where ADate < GETDATE() and PTID > 0 and  PTStatusID <> 812 ;

-- Fetching the latest record as per ADate based on PTID
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_t3;
Select * into temp_t3 from (
    select *,  row_number() over(partition by PTID order by ADate desc) as rn
    from temp_t2
) t
where t.rn = 1 

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_t4;
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN TTID = 2301 and PTStatusID in (800,801) THEN PAmount
            ELSE 0 END AS OAmount
            into temp_t4 from temp_t3

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_t5
Select PID, sum(OAmount) as Final_amt into temp_t5
from  temp_t4  group by PID; 

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CCtbase1
Select * into CCtbase1  from temp_t1 where PID not in 
(Select distinct(PID) from temp_t5 where Final_amt = 0);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CCtbase2
Select a.*, b.EDate, c.EID into CCtbase2 from CCtbase1 a 
left join  TABLE3 b on a.CCID = b.CCID  
left join  TABLE4 c on a.CID = c.CID;
```

Comment: You may want to look at a [Common Table Expression](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), aka CTE. [Example C](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#examples) demonstrates how to use several `select` statements to work, step by step, to a final query. An advantage to using a (non-recursive) CTE is that the query optimizer processes it in one fell swoop so the performance may be much better than the individual steps executed in order.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As no sample data was provided, I've come up with this:

```
WITH T1_CTE as (
    SELECT PID, CID ,CCID, CExpiry, PStatusID, PDate
    FROM  TABLE1 where PStatusID = 1001
),
T2_CTE as (
    SELECT *, CASE WHEN TTID = 2301 AND PTStatusID IN (800,801) THEN PAmount ELSE 0 END AS OAmount
    FROM
    (
        SELECT *, row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY PTID ORDER BY ADate DESC) rowNum
        FROM TABLE2
        WHERE ADate < GETDATE() AND PTID > 0 AND  PTStatusID <> 812
    ) t
    WHERE t.rowNum = 1
),
T2_F_CTE as (
    SELECT PID, SUM(OAmount) as Final_amt
    FROM T2_CTE
    GROUP BY PID
)
SELECT a.*, b.EDate, c.EID
FROM T1_CTE a
LEFT JOIN TABLE3 b ON a.CCID = b.CCID
LEFT JOIN TABLE4 c ON a.CID = c.CID
WHERE PID NOT IN (SELECT PID from T2_F_CTE where Final_amt = 0)
```

This will prevent you from creating too much temporary tables.

Comment: Hi @Zunayed , thank you so much for your response. I have already finished the task based on the suggestion provided by HABO and your reply is very similar to what I've come up with. So accepting this as an answer and upvoted :)

Comment: Thanks, @Charlieface. Didn't notice. And I just barely touched his logic.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this solution

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1(
    PID int, 
    CID int,
    CCID int, 
    CExpiry datetime, 
    PStatusID int, 
    PDate datetime
)

CREATE TABLE TABLE2(
    PID int, 
    ADate DATETIME,
    PTID int,
    PTStatusID int, 
    TTID int, 
    PAmount int
)

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CCtbase1

;with TABLE2CTE(PID,OAmount) as  
(  
SELECT TOP 1 
    PID, CASE 
            WHEN TTID = 2301 AND PTStatusID in (800,801) THEN PAmount
            ELSE 0 
        END AS OAmount 
    FROM TABLE2 
    WHERE 
        ADate < GETDATE() 
        AND PTID > 0 
        AND TTID = 2301 
        AND PTStatusID in (800,801) 
    ORDER BY ADate DESC
)  

SELECT 
    PID, 
    CID, 
    CCID, 
    CExpiry, 
    PStatusID, 
    PDate 
    INTO CCtbase1 
    FROM TABLE1 
    WHERE 
        PID NOT IN 
        (Select distinct(PID) from TABLE2CTE where OAmount = 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but this is not packaging the entire sql statement and I have checked the output is not matching as well but thanks for the idea mate. Upvote deserved